# Which statistic can be used to measure significant text frequency increase?

Tags: statistical-significance, text-mining

I am working on text data. I am interested to find out words that have significantly increased in the recent times. For example, the word 'iTunes' might have appeared 30 times in September, 50 times in October and 60 times in November. Similarly, I have the frequencies for multiple words for a period of time. How can I know if the increase is statistically significant? My objective is to highlight the words which have seen a significant increase recently.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Just how much data do you have over what time periods, how many words do you want to analyse, do you want to do them all simultaneously, and so on?

Comment: I roughly have 1500 words for a period of six months. Eventually, I want to do them all simultaneously and want to highlight the recent surge.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that you're working with specific hypotesis, about specific words. 
You can test your *words of interest*, and use some *random words* (with same length/word class) as controls. For example, if 'helmet' is a word of interest, a control word may be something like 'motorcycle'. Anyway, the word choice strongly depends on what you want to test.

Using those two classes, you can test your hypotesis. For example, you can estimate the frequency increase for all of your words of interest from september to october, and compare those increases with the increase in the random control words frequencies, using a t-test. You can do the same for all of your time intervals. Depending on the amount of time intervals, then, maybe you can consider the implementation of an ANOVA.

Simone

Comment: Thanks @smndpln! I do not have two specific words to compare. Overall, I have 1500 words for 6 months and would like to highlight the words that saw significant increase recently.

Comment: Focus on the term 'significant'. When you say that, what do you mean? There should be a 'baseline' to confront your words with. You can choose zero as a baseline, but only if it makes sense.